# Delete the default "Submit message / Go to page" in the Umbraco Form workflow

Tags: umbraco, umbraco-contour

how do I delete the the default "Submit message / Go to page" in the Umbraco Form workflow?

I want to redirect the page using my action controller.

I'm using Umbraco Form 4.4.2

Thanks,
Romeo

Answer (score 1):

You can leave the submit message etc blank and create your own custom workflow that fires whatever redirect logic you want. Information on workflows here: https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Add-ons/UmbracoForms/Developer/Extending/Adding-a-Workflowtype